# Any other ways to change "With As" for mariadb

Tags: sql-server, database, union, mariadb, recursive-query

```
WITH KPILibHier (kpilib_code,parent_code,kpi_name, depth, iscategory)
AS ( SELECT K.kpilib_code, K.parent_code, K.kpi_name_en, K.kpi_depth, K.iscategory 
     FROM TPMDPERIODKPILIB K 
     INNER JOIN TPMDPERIODKPI PK ON PK.period_code = K.period_code 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT A.kpilib_code, A.parent_code, A.kpi_name_en, A.kpi_depth, A.iscategory 
     FROM TPMDPERIODKPILIB A 
     INNER JOIN KPILibHier AS B ON A.kpilib_code = B.parent_code )
SELECT DISTINCT Z.kpi_name AS libname, Z.kpilib_code AS libcode,
Z.parent_code AS pcode, Z.depth, Z.iscategory, PK.target
FROM KPILibHier Z
LEFT JOIN TPMDPERIODKPILIB KPI 
  ON KPI.kpilib_code = Z.kpilib_code
LEFT JOIN TPMDPERIODKPI PK 
  ON PK.period_code = KPI.period_code 
ORDER BY Z.depth, Z.kpi_name
```

This is my code. 
I could run it in SQL Server, 
But now i have to use Mariadb, 
and Mariadb doesn't use "WITH AS". 
So is there any other way to change this code for the same result?

As we can see, there's "INNER JOIN KPILibHier" too inside the CTE, 
So I couldn't make ordinary subquery as usual.

Comment: Use subquery. Try replacing `KPILibHier` with the content of the `CTE`

Comment: can you give me example please? @FelixPamittan

Answer (score 0):

Just moving the contents of the CTE to a derived table should provide something usable. Something like;

```
SELECT DISTINCT Z.kpi_name AS libname, Z.kpilib_code AS libcode,
Z.parent_code AS pcode, Z.depth, Z.iscategory, PK.target
FROM
( SELECT K.kpilib_code, K.parent_code, K.kpi_name_en AS kpi_name, K.kpi_depth AS depth, K.iscategory 
     FROM TPMDPERIODKPILIB K 
     INNER JOIN TPMDPERIODKPI PK ON PK.period_code = K.period_code 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT A.kpilib_code, A.parent_code, A.kpi_name_en, A.kpi_depth, A.iscategory 
     FROM TPMDPERIODKPILIB A 
     ) z
INNER JOIN z AS B ON A.kpilib_code = B.parent_code 
LEFT JOIN TPMDPERIODKPILIB KPI 
  ON KPI.kpilib_code = Z.kpilib_code
LEFT JOIN TPMDPERIODKPI PK 
  ON PK.period_code = KPI.period_code 
ORDER BY Z.depth, Z.kpi_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but we have to remember that KPILibHier was not a real table. it was the CTE that called KPILibHier. so i will get invalid object KPILibHier return. @mrmoose

Comment: @Febrina - Whoops. Sorry about that. I didn't see your self join in the CTE. I've edited my response to simply perform the self join on the derived table. Does that provide a workable solution, or something you can work from?